# Autosave for GWT on GPE

Tags: eclipse, gwt

The lastest GPE is installed and a GWT project is created in Eclipse 3.7.2.

Before launching GWT `Development Mode`, how to make the `Autosave` feature work if the source files on the current GWT project are modified?

The standard way to enable `Autosave` feature takes no effects on it below,

```
On "Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace"
enabling "Save automatically before build" + "Build automatically"
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be because launching the dev mode is not the same as building the project. But, when there are unsaved changes, a dialog pops up asking you to save the changes before launch. It also has the option of 'Always save the changes before launch'. You can use that to auto saving the changes before launch.

Comment: Weird! The supposed dialog popup has never appealed to me for confirmation on unsaved changes during launching GWT dev mode on GPE.